# Cannot Create Restore Point--says “Insufficient Space”?

Tags: system-restore, windows-7-backup

For years (really), I've been getting this attached screenshot) message when I try to create a restore point (Windows 7). I have PLENTY of space. Because of this error, I haven't been able to make a restore point for years.

I've tried deleting all old restore points (there were 2 from 2011...exactly), and have ensured that Windows Backup and Volume Shadow Copy are turned on (Started in Processes/Services) and in Automatic. Even did a restart on those 2 services. Still no luck. I feel like I've tried a few other things from all my googling, but still getting that error and can't make a restore point.

Thanks for helping me out. None of my independent research (hours every few months) is getting me anywhere. Thanks.

PS I've already tried the few items on 2 other articles including "System Restore is not creating restore points" article, thanks.

I think the person who ends up having the actual solution (not just identify the problem) will be a true genius.

Comment: Did you check your event log for details error messages?

Answer (score 0):

How much space is allocated to System Protection?

[image: System Protection]

```
 delete
 I would try **Turn off system protection**
 reboot
 Turn it back ON
 Allow it at least 3gb to 4gb if not more.
```

Does any of this help?

Comment: I tried your 3 steps to no avail. Same exact error. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if when you say, you 'have plenty of space', it's in the right place.

While you might have plenty of space in the C drive, **I'm pretty sure the restore points are placed in the D drive**, and not the primary partition.  You need to take a look at how your drive is partitioned.

Take a look at this tool:  `Computer Management` | `Storage` | `Disk  management`

[image]

Comment: HEY, THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER! I went into Disk Mgmt, and have attached mine. By the way, I use Bootcamp Windows7 on Imac, if that helps you understand my partitions, etc. My "D" drive, by the way, is just my internal DVD drive I use for backups. Can you have a look at my attachment for my Disk Mgmt (dropbox link), and see if it's workable?  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ka0esjsz4tengb1/My%20Disk%20Management%20%28is%20it%20set%20up%20right%20so%20that%2C%20like%20you%20said%2C%20%27D%27%20drive%20takes%20restore%20points.%20My%20%27D%27%20is%20my%20backup%20DVD%20drive%20%28optical%20drive%29.bmp

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about macs.  However I can see that you don't have a drive called 'RECOVERY'.  Also, I think you might want to edit your question above and call more attention to 'Bootcamp' on OSx.  Until now I was under the impression you were on a straight up Win-7 system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks EV. Honestly, I don't think it matters. Bootcamp is just a simple idea of partitioning some of Mac's hard drive to IOS + Windows. That's all. People complicate it unnecessarily. I had had successful system restore points for years. For some reason, though, related to that error I gave, I can't restore. Searching all over the web, many people have the same error as me, unrelated to Bootcamp.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried increasing the system page file size and/or changing the page file directory or drive? May be a long shot but worth a go.